# Finding Last Row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a macro to update key cells from a form, then write the data to a table in a second sheet. To do this, I'm using a For i = 1 to LR to match, then write the Row number to a variable if it finds a match.

However the code to find the last row, and therefore the length of the loop isn't working as expected.

```
Dim LR as Long

LR = Cells(Workbooks("Tracking Sheet.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 

Debug.Print LR
```

I've tried pre-populating both less than 25 and more than 25 (e.g. 38) , but the LR variable is always showing 25 in the Immediate window. In the immediate window,

```
?Cells(Workbooks("Tracking Sheet.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

returns 38, as it should.

```
LR = Cells(Workbooks("Tracking Sheet.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

?LR

also returns 38

I just don't get it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim LR As Long

With Application.Workbooks("Tracking Sheet.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")

LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

Comment: To explain what was wrong here: You actually used `Cells` without referencing a sheet. So this is the same as `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells` which is probably not the same as `Workbooks("Tracking Sheet.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")`. So you were actually looking in the wrong sheet.

Comment: That took care of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the code explained will help?

```
LRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

Let's break up this code. First, we place it in a `With` statement to save us some typing

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

Let's break this up in pieces. First, there is `.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A")`
This is a reference to a single cell. Specifically, the very last row in column A of `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)`. `Rows.Count` gives the last row number in the Excel sheets. Recent Excel versions support 1,048,576 rows, but e.g. Excel 97 only supported 65536 rows.
In short, `.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A")` is for recent excel versions equal to (A1048576)

Then `End(xlUp)`. This does the same as when you hold CTRL and press the arrow up button on your keyboard. This brings Excel to the first filled row from the bottom.

Finally `.Row`, which returns the row number of this found cell.

---

You could also start looking from the the top. Try holding CTRL and then pressing the arrow down button. This would stop at the last non-empty cell. However, it would also stop when you have blank cells between filled cells. So, not always a preferred method. The code would be

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    LRow = .Cells(1, "A").End(xlDown).Row
End With
```